# Media queries on internet explorer 11 reading only the first one

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I'm trying to make a few @media to work on internet explorer 11

```
.content {
    border-top: 1px solid #939393;
    border-right: 1px solid #939393;
    border-left: 1px solid #939393;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-top: -60px;
    position: relative;
    width: 99.7%;
    z-index: 97;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1330px) {
    .content{
        width: 99.6%;
        z-index: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .content{
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 99.6%;
        z-index: 0;
}

/* Tablet - 800px, 768px & 720px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .content{
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 99.6%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}


/* Mobile - 480px & 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {
    .content{
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 99.45%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}


/* Mobile - 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .content{
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}
```

Internet explorer 11 is only reading the first media query which is max-width: 1330px even if I reduce the screen width to a minimum.

This only happens with internet explorer. Firefox, chrome, opera, etc.. do work as intended and read the other media queries.

Am I missing something? How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a few closing `}` I have formatted your code so you can see it easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error so IE only parses the first query.

Close your declarations.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1330px) {
    .content{
    width: 99.6%;
    z-index: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .content{
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 99.6%;
    z-index: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: We've all been there :}